# Firebird isql error dont show in output file

Tags: command, firebird, isql

When I run isql with a script file:

```
isql.exe -q -e -i %1 -o %~n1.log
```

Then in the output file I see commands, but the error of commands I see on the screen when it run.

The Error doesn't isn't written to the output file. Which command should I use so the errors are also written to the output file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `-m(erge)` command line switch in order to send the error messages into the output file.

Comment: See also the [Firebird ISQL manual](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/isql.html)